# What if I changed my subnet mask from 255.255.255.0 to 255.255.255.255 on my Windows, will I be able to communicate with other hosts on my LAN?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, wireless-networking, routing

Few days back, when I was surfing the admin panel of my router, I had found an IP address. I knew that this IP address was assigned to my router by my ISP. Also I knew that there are few other users like me who were taking service from same ISP. So their router would have IP in the same network as my WiFi router. I used my WiFi router's IP and subnet of 255.255.255.0 and ran a nmap scan. I found multiple IP addresses.

Also I dig down further and found they were running admin panels for WiFi router. However after some days I am unable to access any of the IP addresses which I scanned using nmap. Possibly my ISP has blocked me to do so. I was wondering is by changing the subnet of my router because when I checked my admin panel, I found the subnet of 255.255.255.255 for my router, for the interface connecting to modem.

The subnet of 255.255.255.255 might be a possible reason I am not able to communicate with other devices connected to my ISP's modem. I did an experiment of changing my Windows subnet to 255.255.255.255 and ping my phone's IP address 10.25.0.100. However I was able to ping perfeclty. So anyone could explain me why I am not able to communicate with other devices on the network on modem side. If subnet is the reason then how I am able to ping my smartphone?

Screenshot for subnet and ping details on my Windows machine:

[image: Screenshot for subnet & ping details on my windows machine]

Comment: There are no other devices connected. Just google CG-NAT.